# App crashes on launch adding button code to mainActivity

Tags: java, android, xml, button, navigation-drawer

My app crash when I launch it after adding code to my Main activity to click on a button and output the results from one textbox to another. Without the button code, it runs grand and opens the navigation drawer on launch. Any help would be appreciated.

Logcat

```
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131): Process: com.draco.dragonmessage, PID: 17131
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.draco.dragonmessage/com.draco.dragonmessage.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class fragment
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5144)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class fragment
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at com.draco.dragonmessage.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:145)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    ... 11 more
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #31: Duplicate id 0x7f080002, tag null, or parent id 0x7f080000 with another fragment for com.draco.dragonmessage.NavigationDrawerFragment
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4791)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
06-04 10:05:47.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17131):    ... 22 more
06-04 10:40:57.015: D/ActivityThread(18803): handleBindApplication:com.draco.dragonmessage
06-04 10:40:57.015: D/ActivityThread(18803): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
06-04 10:40:57.015: D/ActivityThread(18803): setTargetHeapMinFree:524288
06-04 10:40:57.245: D/AndroidRuntime(18803): Shutting down VM
06-04 10:40:57.245: W/dalvikvm(18803): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41841ce0)
06-04 10:40:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18803): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 10:40:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18803): Process: com.draco.dragonmessage, PID: 18803
06-04 10:40:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18803): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.draco.dragonmessage/com.draco.dragonmessage.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 10:40:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18803):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
06-04 10:40:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18803):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
06-04 10:40:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18803):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
06-04 10:40:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18803):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
06-04 10:40:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18803):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-04 10:40:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18803):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-04 10:40:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18803):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5144)
06-04 10:40:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18803):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 10:40:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18803):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-04 10:40:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18803):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
06-04 10:40:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18803):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
06-04 10:40:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18803):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 10:40:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18803): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 10:40:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18803):    at com.draco.dragonmessage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
06-04 10:40:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18803):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-04 10:40:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18803):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-04 10:40:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18803):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
06-04 10:40:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18803):    ... 11 more
```

MainActivity

```
package com.draco.dragonmessage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    String sendMessageString = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

       final Button sendMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.messageButton); 
       System.out.println(sendMessage.toString());
            sendMessage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final TextView receivedMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textReceived);
                final EditText messageToSend = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSend);
                sendMessageString = messageToSend.toString();
                receivedMessage.setText(sendMessageString);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }
    }
```

main_activity.xml

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using                match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.draco.dragonmessage.MainActivity" >

<!--
     As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
-->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!--
     android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead.
-->
<!--
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container.
-->

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.draco.dragonmessage.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.draco.dragonmessage.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter message to send..." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textReceived"
        android:text="Keith"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textReceived"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editTextSend"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/messageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextSend"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your onCreateView you are inflating the wrong layout. This

```
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
```

should be

```
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity, container, false);
```